# Не выводятся картинки из базы данных Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сделать приложение-галерею на Джанго. Картинки через админку грузятся, при указании абсолютной ссылки на картинку - отображает, но когда пытаюсь вывести списком - ничего не показывает.

urls.py проекта

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from pictures import views
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('pictures/', include('pictures.urls')),
    path('', include('pictures.urls')),
    path('gallery/', include('pictures.urls'))  ,
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py приложения

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PictureDetailView,
    PictureListView
)


urlpatterns = [

    path('<int:pk>/', PictureDetailView.as_view(), name='picture_detail'),
    path('', PictureListView.as_view(), name='home'),  
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Picture
from .forms import PictureForm
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


# Create your views here.


class PictureListView(ListView):
    model = Picture
    template_name='home.html'
    context_object_name='picture_list'
    login_url = 'login'





class PictureDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Picture
    template_name='picture_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'picture'
    login_url = 'login'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.

class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('picture_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


    @property
    def photo_url(self):
        if self.photo and hasattr(self.photo, 'url'):
            return self.photo.url
```

html шаблон

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} ^_^ All arts ^_^ {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {% for picture in picture_list %}

        <img src="{{ piture.photo_url }}">

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} ^_^ All arts ^_^ {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    {% for picture in picture_list %}

        <img src="{{ picture.photo_url }}">

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

У вас опечатся в `img` в слове **picture**

Comment: там же @property есть, так что второе не актуально по идее .

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin май бэд, проглядел метод.

Comment: сам хотел писать про опечатку с _ , а вот 2 не заметил)